# Laravel: How to create a method in Model that returns verified users?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

The `users` table has `verified` column with boolean type.

How to create a method in `User` Model that returns only verified users instead of all() method ?

For example: `User::verifiedUsers();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Local scopes allow you to define common sets of constraints that you may easily re-use throughout your application.

Use [scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#local-scopes) like this:

```php
    public function scopeVerified($query)
    {
        return $query->where('verified', true);
    }
```

So you can use it:

```php
User::verified()->get();
// add more condition:
User::verified()->where(...)->get();
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. I would add a little polish to it by renaming the method `scopeVerified` so it writes a little cleaner. `User::verified()->all();` `verifiedUsers` on the `User` model seems redundant.

Comment: @Mark Good advice. thx.